# Пунктуация — две грамматические основы?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, грамматическая-основа

> У вас, случайно, не будет свободного времени(,) племянника навестить?

Добрый день. Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли на выделенном месте запятая, если по звучанию там можно было бы поставить союз чтобы?

Comment: Да, лучше поставить, но еще лучше не создавать таких, перегруженных сомнениями, фраз, особенно если это касается обращений. "Скажите, когда вы сможете навестить племянника?" - как-нибудь так, если, конечно, не стоит задачи усложнить и закрутить с какой-то целью. "Не будет свободного времени" - слишком сложно и утверждение через отрицание, такое себе выражение...

Comment: По слуху – согласна, запятая нужна, не хватает только грамматического обоснования.  Это разговорная речь, записать ее сложнее, чем книжную, но это уже проблемы того, кто записывает.  С точки зрения правильности  сказанного всё корректно и понятно, и  перестройка сообщения не требуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях по правилам ставится тире: *У вас, случайно, не будет свободного времени – **племянника навестить?***

Тире обозначает увеличенную паузу. Если паузу **не подчеркивать,** то можно предположить, что тире заменяется запятой: *У вас, случайно, не будет свободного времени,  **племянника навестить?***

**Пояснение**

1. Время (какое?) навестить –  здесь инфинитив в роди **несогласованного определения**. Сравнить: желание (какое?) остаться.
2. Но в данном случае определение обособляется **тире**. Это связано с тем, что сущ. уже имеет согласованное определение; кроме того, инфинитив не примыкает непосредственно к сущ.
3. [Правило Розенталя: п. 11.](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm)

Обособляются и отделяются **при помощи тире** несогласованные определения, выраженные неопределенной формой глагола, перед которой можно без ущерба для смысла поставить слова «**а именно**», например: Я шел к вам с чистыми побуждениями, с единственным желанием – сделать добро! (Чехов); Но прекрасен данный жребий – просиять и умереть (Брюсов).

4. **Для проверки** обстоятельственного значения используется подстановка союза ***ЧТОБЫ:*** *У вас, случайно, не будет свободного времени, **чтобы племянника навестить?*** Это СПП с придаточным цели, здесь действительно две основы: придаточное предложение односоставное, сказуемое выражено инфинитивом.

**Приложение**

[Каким членом может быть инфинитив](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/kakoi-chlen-predlozheniya-infinitiv.html#i-4)